# LightGBM - Binary Classification using train API

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, lightgbm

I have a binary classification problem which I'm trying to solve using LightGBM's train and cv APIs. 
First I have tuned the hyperparameters by using hyperopt together with an objective function that wraps the LightGBM CV API call. For that, since the target classes are highly unbalanced, I've used the customized focal loss function with f1-score evaluation to find the best fit. 
When I try to fit the final model using the optimized parameters, the model doesn't consider it as a binary problem and outputs continuous values at prediction. See the attached image.
Anyone knows what I'm missing ?
[Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5S9.png)

Comment: Hi, I read that in combination with custom loss functions, you have to deal with values that are not between 0 and 1, but have to apply a sigmoid function to translate light gbm's output to values in the range between zero and one. Not sure, if that explains your observation, but maybe it helps.